# ExtJS 6 view autoloader issue

Tags: extjs, autoloader

ExtJS 6.5.0: in application it's used

```
appFolder: '/app/document/app'
```

But it looks like not workable for views:

```
>> Ext.Loader.getPath('Document');
/app/document/app

>> Ext.Loader.getPath('Document.view.main.Main');
classic/src/view/main/Main.js
{OR} modern/src/view/main/Main.js
// Expected:
// /app/document/app/classic/src/view/main/Main.js
// OR /app/document/app/modern/src/view/main/Main.js

>> Ext.Loader.getPath('Document.main.Main');
/app/document/app/main/Main.js
```

Could anyone suggest a solution for that?

---

Steps to reproduce the issue:

```
sencha generate workspace ./
sencha framework add ~/extjs/6.5.0 ext
sencha -sdk ext generate app Document ./app/document

nano ./app/document/app.js
> + appFolder: '/app/documents/app',
```

Move index file two folders up... open console and check commands from the top.

---

P.S. I've made a hack in `Ext.beforeLoad` to resolve it, but I need a solution directly "out of the box"

Comment: [It works in a minimal example](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1up1), so don't expect a solution from us...

Comment: Possibly, but not in case of "classic" and "modern" builds, when views are in a separate folders [(classic|modern)/src/view]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an approach from https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?269448-Cmd-3-1-2-Ext-Loader-path-prefix :

> To dynamically load the assets from other than the page-location's context, without using the base tag I think one really does have to mess with the loader configuration. Something like:
>
> Code:

```
Ext.Loader.setPath({
    "Ext":              "http://path/ext/src",
    "MyApp":            "http://path/app",
    "MyApp.model":      "http://path/app/model",
    "MyApp.view":       "http://path/app/view",
    "MyApp.controller": "http://path/app/controller",
    "MyApp.store":      "http://path/app/store",
    "MyApp.extras":     "http://path/app/extras"
```

});

> The namespace needs to be "over-specified" because Ext.application will trash the autoloader's MyApp path by overriding it with the value of MyApp.appFolder (which is really not supposed to be an absolute path; even Architect won't allow you to set one.)

Answer (score 2):

I think you have create a `Universal` application.

`Universal` application has two separate folders for `classic` and `modern` views.

EXTJS 6 will expect all views files in `classic` or in `modern` folder for respective type, and it will lodes views at run time according to your loading descriptor. which you can give at run time.

> Ext.manifest = 'classic' or 'modern';

[image]

Comment: It's true, and I need to use both of them. So, I've expected to see:

    Ext.Loader.getPath('Document.view.main.Main');
    /app/document/app/classic/src/view/main/Main.js
or
    /app/document/app/modern/src/view/main/Main.js

Comment: After you production build there will be two folder created in build  (classic|modern) and at a time only one will loaded according to your 'Ext.manifest'  config. so in browser you will get only one file of 'Document.main.Main" either from classic folder or modern folder. You can not get both of them at same time.

Comment: that's definitely clear, and I'm NOT going to use them at the same time (while I can use URL part to check each of them separately)... the path is needed to be aligned with prefix `'/app/document/app'` for `view`s, and it's what the question about

Comment: For  Ext.Loader.getPath('Document.view.main.Main'); you will get "app/document/app/view/main/Main.js" with this configuration in "app.js" name: 'Document',
appFolder: 'app/document/app'

Comment: No, it's not so... for Modern and Classic I have different views in related folders (modern/classic), and they have to stay. The only thing that I would like to change - switch relative paths to direct